# Wordnet (JWI): Get example sentences for a word

Tags: java, wordnet, jwi

I'm trying to implement the Lesk Algorithm for word sense disambiguation using Wordnet and it's Java API JWI. One of the steps requires to build a bag of words from the gloss and example sentences of the target word. I can easily get the gloss from the method getGloss() in class ISynset, but I don't see a method to get the example sentences. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious since JWI is described as "full-featured" on wordnet's site, but i can't find anything useful in the documentation or the internet. How do I get those sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be there. Examples are attached to synsets (e.g. they are a sibling function to getting lemmas and definitions in the NLTK API), but the [2.4.0 JWI docs](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/api/) for `synset` only have functions for `getGloss()` and `getWords()`.

(If it turns out there is a way to get them from JWI, can someone leave me a comment, and I'll then delete this answer.)